Deactivate specific linter in spotless/ktlint
I'm new to Kotlin, and I'm updating an old repository that hadn't any linter yet.
I installed spotless/ktlint, and with the default configuration in build.gradle.ts, I've got the following error:
spotless {
    kotlin {
        target("**/src/**/*.kt")
        ktlint()
    }
    kotlinGradle {
        target("**/*.gradle.kts")
        ktlint()
    }
}

The error message:
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':spotlessKotlin'.
> Error on line: 1, column: 9
  rule: standard:package-name
  Package name must not contain underscore

I know where the error is, but as the project is quite big, I'd prefer to temporarily deactivate this specific linter (and all the others that are likely to fail and long to correct), but I didn't find any way to deactivate this specific error.
By going into the code, I was able to restrict to a few linters, but I feel like I'm missing a lot of them.
spotless {
    kotlin {
        target("**/src/**/*.kt")
        ktlint()
        clearSteps()
        endWithNewline()
        indentWithSpaces(4)
        trimTrailingWhitespace()
    }
    kotlinGradle {
        target("**/*.gradle.kts")
        ktlint()
    }
}

So, I have two questions:

Where can I find a list of all the available linters ?
If I'm correct, my second code uses a whitelist of linters to use. Is there a way to tell the code "I want to activate ALL the linters, minus those in my list"?

An additional question : is this the best linter ? Are there other options that would be better?

endWithNewline is one of the few general purpose steps of spotless, you can find more in FormatExtension docs.
What you need is to suppress individual ktlint rules:
ktlint()
suppressLintsFor {
    step = "ktlint"
    shortCode = "standard:package-name"
}
suppressLintsFor {
    step = "ktlint"
    shortCode = "standard:no-wildcard-imports"
}
suppressLintsFor {
    step = "ktlint"
    shortCode = "standard:no-empty-file"
}

The one you need is standard:package-name. You can find more standard ktlint rules here. All rules from the standard and custom rule sets are enabled by default.
There is also expiremental rule set, which can be enabled in .editorconfig file. The process of setting .editorconfig file is described in spotless docs.
Default value is the .editorconfig file located in the top project. You can also set its path with setEditorConfigPath function or override it entirely with editorConfigOverride function.
It is possible to suppress rules in editorconfig too, but some rules cannot be suppressed this way.
spotless {
    kotlin {
        ktlint()
            .setEditorConfigPath("$projectDir/config/.editorconfig")  // sample unusual placement
            .editorConfigOverride(
                mapOf(
                    "ktlint_experimental" to "enabled",  // enable a rule set
                    "ktlint_standard_filename" to "disabled",  // disable a rule
                )
            )
    }
}

editorConfigOverride options will override what's supplied in .editorconfig file.

Thanks, it seems to be exactly what I need, but I still have an issue : When I try it, "suppressLintsFor" is not recognized. I feel I'm missing an import, but I didn't find anything in the spotless repo : https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adiffplug%2Fspotless%20suppressLintFor&type=code

What version of spotless plugin do you use? Support for suppressLintsFor was added in 7.0.0, latest version currently is 7.0.0.BETA4. Even if you don't want to use a beta version you can still suppress with .editorConfigOverride. Also there is a typo in your link, suppressLintFor instead of plural suppressLintsFor. @OrangeLux

I was using version 7.0.0.BETA3, I just upgraded to BETA4.

Apparently, it was just a cache problem on my IDE. Now it works perfectly, thanks a lot !
